# sql SELECT query with certain conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

I have the MySQL table with 2 rows that is "name" for user name and "port" for user port.

i want to get port number from port row when i get some condition,

**example: i want to get Louis' port number if nama = Louis**

NOTE: I use JDBC

What MySQL command should I use?

I've tried this command (below) but still failed:

```
 ResultSet rslset = statement.executeQuery("select cast(case when 
 nama='"+name+"') port from user");
```

NOTE: Variable "name" is the name that will be checked

Comment: You are saying that the same table has two separate rows one for the port and one for the user? How do you know which port corresponds to which user?

Comment: How is the name record related to the port record? Perhaps you could provide the sample data and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ResultSet rslset = statement.executeQuery("select port from user where nama='"+name+"'");
```

Answer (score 2):

try to use **[PreparedStatement](http://www.roseindia.net/jdbc/jdbc-mysql/TwicePreparedStatement.shtml)**

```
/** other codes here **/
String sql = "SELECT port FROM user WHERE nama = ?";
/** con is you active Connection **/
PreparedStatement prest = con.prepareStatement(sql);
prest.setString(1, name); /** this is where you assign the parameter **/
ResultSet rs1 = prest.executeQuery();
/** other codes here **/
```

this will avoid you from sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select port from user where name='(nameyouwant)';
```

I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

type query like this in your statement....

```
"select port from user where nama='Louis'"
```